# goog.locale: TypeError: Cannot read property 'COUNTRY' of undefined

Tags: locale, google-closure

I am using `goog.locale.getlocalizedcountryname' function in my code to get localized full country names from country codes eg 'en-US'.

```
goog.locale.getLocalizedCountryName('en-US')  // Actual implementation contains variablename.
```

gives `TypeError: Cannot read property 'COUNTRY' of undefined`.

Also

```
goog.locale.getResource('LocaleNameConstants', goog.locale.getLocale())
```

gives `undefined` (went on debugging to find this)

What am I missing?

Comment: This works with `goog.locale.getLocalizedCountryName('en-US', goog.locale.nativeNameConstants)`, but from the docs this doesn't seem to be the intended usage, as the second argument is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_locale_locale.js.source.html#line161

> This method depends on goog.locale.LocaleNameConstants__
>   available from `http://go/js_locale_data`. User of this method has to
>   add dependency to this.

also:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-library-discuss/1fQ-GmNmLgM

> We're deprecating the goog.locale package in favor of the goog.i18n
>   functions, which don't require the mysterious locale data referenced
>   in the comments (it's just a directory filled with translated strings,
>   which is now obsolete).

Comment: Good catch by referring the code. though the docs don't say anything about this. Also `goog.i18n`, atm can't replace `goog.locale` as it doesn't provide locale/country data.